# Why does Zeref want to kill Acnologia?

Tags: fairy-tail

Why does Zeref want to kill Acnologia so badly? Is there something I missed entirely? Or has it just not been said yet?

I'm not sure if this is explained in the manga because I've only watched the anime.

Comment: If you want an answer you have to expect spoilers.

Comment: Well I've seen the entire anime twice through, but I was just wondering if there's something I missed that was hinted at. My question was has anything been said about it in the anime? If it's not I just need a simple "no but it has been said in the manga"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far there is no information regarding Acnologia's motives so far even in the manga. I haven't seen Anime post the Grand Magic games so putting everything in spoilers. Read at your own risk. But I assume Anime has covered everything till the 2nd spoiler, but not sure about the third.

Following is the information that we have on him. [Acnologia](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Acnologia) (Chapter 301).

> Born over 400 years ago, Acnologia was one of the first Dragon Slayers to come into being, entering the Dragon Civil War on the side supporting coexistence. Acnologia and a group of other Dragon Slayers, however, disregarded the cause their comrades fought for, and killed every Dragon they could, bathing in their blood. Due to the overuse of his Magic, Acnologia's physique eventually turned into that of a Dragon's, and he proclaimed himself to be the Dragon King. This event was forever etched into history as the Dragon King Festival.

We see the following in the Tartaros Arc (Chapter 412-415),

> Acnologia appears again at the ruins of Cube where the battle between Fairy Tail Mages and Tartaros takes place.[..] Acnologia fights the Dragon King Igneel and loses his left arm, however in return, Acnologia destroys nearly the entire left half of Igneel's torso and then kills him with his Dragon's Roar. With his arm gone and his target slain, Acnologia then leaves Magnolia.

One year later we see Zeref and Acnologia meet.

> One year after losing his arm to Igneel, Acnologia accepts Zeref's proposal to meet, and does so at an undisclosed rocky terrain, albeit in his human form instead of as a Dragon. Acnologia asks what Zeref wants; however, he is met with curiosity, as **Zeref points out that Acnologia could rule the world with his power if he wished, calling his motives unfathomable**. Acnologia, however, says the same of Zeref's motives. **He then listens as Zeref tells him that he will not join or fight against Acnologia; rather, he will kill Acnologia along with everyone else in the world**. He further implies that Acnologia has been waiting for someone to give him a true challenge and Zeref claims that he will gladly take on the role of challenger for Acnologia. Acnologia then gives a sly grin as Zeref tells him to wait for the ultimate clash between human, Dragon, and immortal to approach.

This makes me think that Zeref wants to kill Acnologia just because he wants to kill everything in the world. Acnologia is maybe just as powerful as Zeref and thus deserves a special mention.

Comment: Thank you Arcane! The whole thing isn't because of some rivalry, just because Acnologia is powerful, and is on Zeref hit list. I did not open the last one so I hope that it didn't contain too much information on it! But thank you so much for clarifying it.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to because Acnologia's goal is to kill all humans, and so is Zeref's. But Acnologia is much stronger than Zeref, and since he can't die, Zeref is scared that he will spend an eternity as a play toy for Acnologia.

Comment: Almost correct. Technically, Zeref's goal is to end his own life. He wants to be mortal and to achieve that, he doesn't care how many lives would be sacrificed. He doesn't put killing everyone as his goal.